# How to get user's location from Facebook chatbot api

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I was wondering how I could get a user's location from a Facebook messenger chatbot. What I want to accomplish is the following: the chatbot will say something like "Please send me your location", and then the user would tap the "Share Location" on the Facebook messenger app. I have figured out how to get a textual message that the user sends, but not the location. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location can be obtained as well as text. More precisely, as the photo.
You need take `message.attachments.payload.coordinates`. Also you can check `message.attachments.type`.

example:

```
{
   "object": "page",
   "entry": [{
       "id": "1719442148306048",
       "time": 1466780344978,
       "messaging": [{
           "sender": {"id": "123456789"},
           "recipient": {"id": "987654321"},
           "timestamp": 1466780344847,
           "message": {
               "mid": "mid.12345698875:c80066d69b6cee1779",
               "seq": 65,
               "attachments": [{
                   "title": "Dmitry's Location",
                   "url": "Link to bing.com through facebook redirect"
                   "type": "location",
                   "payload": {"coordinates": {"lat": 55, "long": 37}}
               }]
           }
       }]
   }]
}
```

Comment: What does payload mean?

Comment: I was wondering if you could explain this more. I just got dropped a Facebook messaging app that was started by another person; this appears to solve what I am looking for but it's unlcear how to implement it. Any more info. thx -jt

Comment: Here is a more in-depth explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277397/facebook-messenger-chatbot-how-do-i-collect-the-users-geo-location-that-they-sen