# Is it Possible to Fetch User current location using Graph.Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have searched alot about graph.api ... I want to fetch user's current location ...by location i don't mean about the location which he have mentioned in his facebook profile,

I am making a Bot using graph.api and Api.Ai,  which will fetch users current location and on the basis of his location bot will suggest restaurants in the radius of 5km around him ....if user move from that place after certain time bot fetch his location again and suggest some more restaurants...

I want to know that does graph.api allow this thing ? and if yes can i have some reference link or code example .  Thankyou

Comment: No. You have to ask the user to send the location to the bot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277397/facebook-messenger-chatbot-how-do-i-collect-the-users-geo-location-that-they-sen

Comment: why not user google api geo location to get the current location of your users?

Comment: my app will be link with facebook